# Change screen with change language using Localization

Tags: android

I change language of application using following code

```
 myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

but I want to change screen with selected language programmatically 
eg. If I select english we are using ltr format
    If I use arabic then rtl format.

If I put  android:supportsRtl="true" in manifest.xml then work I change language from setting,But I want it handle programmatically.Is this possible?